# HTML select element - Selected item use option font

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am creating a font dropdown list on a web page. I have styled each option element with the font that it represents:-

```
<option value="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Arial</option>
```

When I expand the dropdown it looks correct but when I select an item, the dropdown does not use the font of the selected option. Is there a way I can make it update the font when selecting options?

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bq2d9/

Comment: You say it looks correct when expanding, but I don't see it working. Tested latest Chrome and IE9.

Comment: All the fonts seem to appear in Arial. This is the selected font by default.

Comment: To me its showing correct, using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add:

```
onChange="this.style.fontFamily=this.value;"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bq2d9/5/

Do note that the font in the drop-down displays properly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. However, after selection, both will display the text in the correct font.

Chrome does not support different fonts in each selection option.

---

To get a cross-browser font selector that displays the font of each option, you will have to get a plugin.

Looking at jQuery plugins, there are a large number. It is unclear exactly which of them support individual styling. I can find a few where options can be individually styled, however, they also can look ugly. For the ones which look better, it is sometimes hard to know whether they can be individually styled.

The best I can find is jQuery-Font-Chooser - https://github.com/CD1212/jQuery-Font-Chooser. It looks good enough, and response time is ok.

Otherwise, for other plugins, you can search, for example, "jquery select box" or "jquery font selector".

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I have been using Firefox so I hadn't realized this wasn't working on Chrome and IE. I guess there is no way to get it working in those browsers?

Comment: To get it working cross-browser, you will need a select box plugin. Updated answer above, and found a possible font selector you could use.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rp9gp/1/

Try this to change the style in the dropdown:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rp9gp/2/

Comment: This is a nice example but it is not what I wanted to acheive, I would like to make the select box use the selected font.

Comment: I will try to add, one second.  I didn't know that's what you were asking.

Comment: Go ahead and try the second link.

Comment: second link is incorrect... font is not chainging for dropdown

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need some customization that every browser might not support and you will face problems like the one you mentioned. So I certainly recommend you to use a fully customized combobox. A jquery one might be good for you.

Here is the link to ComboBox plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/combobox